# How to loop through all the objects with a specific "name"?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

Okay, so here I don't mean name as an attribute I give it to the object, rather, the object name.

For example,

If I have:

```
{
    SKSpriteNode *_one;
    SKSpriteNode *_two;
}
```

and now I want all the _two to disappear, what should I do?

Traditionally, I can do this:

```
_two.name = @"two"
```

and then use a for loop like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (SKSpriteNode *node in self.children) {
        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"two"]){
            //Make them disappear here.
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this is pretty difficult. I want some code like this:

```
{
    SKSpriteNode *_one;
    SKSpriteNode *_two;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (/*some code that picks up all the "_two"s*/) {
        //Make them disappear here.
    }
}
```

**These are wrong**:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    ////ATTENTION!!!!////

    for (_two in self.children) {

    ////ATTENTION!!!!////

        //Make them disappear here.
    }
}
```

If you have methods, please share!!! Thanks.

Comment: Why is this question marked as unclear? The point is clear: Aero just wants to make the nodes marked with a specific name property to be removed from their parent. This is related to Sprite Kit, and flagged by people who apparently do not know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sprite Kit has an inbuilt method for that.

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"two" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        [node removeFromParent];
}];
```

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/enumerateChildNodesWithName%3ausingBlock%3a):

> This method enumerates the child array in order, searching for nodes
>   whose name matches the search parameter. The block is called once for
>   each node that matches the name parameter.

Comment: this should be the correct answer, store skspritenode in an array and use nspredicate as other answer suggest, is no-sense for me. sprite kit has this wonderful method, and this should be used

Answer (score 2):

There is no connection between the *name* of a variable used to hold object references and any object it references at any point in time. Furthermore an object does not have a name as such; they have addresses - the value that is stored in variables that reference them. So what you are asking simply does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are storing all your SKSpriteNode objects in array. So you can use  `NSPredicate` to filter data conditionally.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@ ",@"two"];
NSArray *allTwos = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
for (SKSpriteNode *node in allTwos) {
        //Make them disappear here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to try and do it this way. First, it doesn't seem possible to introspect the name of an object, though you can easily do it for the class. Second, while you have only two objects it seems practical but when you get more you'll want to start doing it based on partial names and things will get slow if you start having to do multiple partial string comparisons on many objects all the time.

Try using the `userData` property inherited from SKNode. If you need to record that a node is of a particular class or is going to stop being needed at a particular time that looks like the best way to do it.

If your nodes are all in an array, you can get all the ones you want to act on (make disappear...) with `- (NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate` - write a predicate to filter all of the nodes with some userData key that you have set.